# Changing the color of a textbox text when we write a new one

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, css, .net

I have this input text in my application

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="note"  runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Note")%>' />
```

The default `Foreground-color` is **Black** .I'd like to change this property when i write in textbox, the letters will be in another color like **Red**.

So :

1. What is the easiest way to do this?
2. Did  a property in the `<asp:TextBox />` which can do this exists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest way to do this is with CSS. Add following class:

```
#note:focus {
    color: red
}
```

When the textbox receives focus and ready to accept text - the color will be turned to red.

As an alternative, if for some reason you need to do this inline - you can, but this time with JavaScript. Modify your textbox like this:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="note"  runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Note")%>' onfocus="this.style.color='red'" onblur="this.style.color='black'" />
```

This will achieve the same results as above.

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/S48tb/**